# VBA, Excel. Execute code that offsets & resizes a range & then copies it. "Compile error: Invalid watch expression"

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors, watch

I'm trying to offset,resize and copy a range containing data and is typing this line of code in the immediate window:

```
shAll.Range("A1:I78").Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count - 
1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).copy
```

When I press enter I get this error: "Compile error: Invalid watch expression"

Is it a syntax issue?

This part of the code it working fine when executed in the immediate window:

```
shAll.Range("A1:I78").Offset(1).select
```

It's getting offseted the way I want. The remaining part is to resize and copy it.

By the way, the range `shAll.Range("A1:I78")` contains data in all cells.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not specified which object `.Rows` and `.Columns` apply to.

If they apply to the range then

```
With shAll.Range("A1:I78")
    .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).copy
End with
```

or

```
shAll.Range("A1:I78").Offset(1).Resize(shAll.Range("A1:I78").Rows.Count - 1, _
shAll.Range("A1:I78").Columns.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).copy
```

Comment: This is it, now it works! :) And you really taught me a very useful insight today. An object needs to be specified and can be done in the ways you described. Thank you very much Gareth!

Answer (score 0):

You can do a name range or put the actual range that you need.

```
Worksheets("Sheet").Range("namedrange_d").Resize(, 4).Offset(6, 0).Copy _
  Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("namedrange").Resize(, 4).Offset(6, 0)
```

Comment: Are you saying that the part (.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count - 
1) is'nt possible to execute in the immediate window? Do I have to specify it as fixed numbers?

Comment: I'm just inteterested to know why I'm getting an error with the code I'm using. The code is from an online course so I know it works, but in the course they are using a variable range and looks like this:  shAll.Range("A1:I" & LastRow)Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy. I just want to test the code in the immediate window using a fixed range instead.